# Combining / deduplicating contacts in Windows 8 People app

Tags: windows-8, contacts, windows-8-people-app

Is there a way of combining or deduplicating contacts in the Windows 8 People app? For some reason I have double entries of many contacts (with identical names), and the app isn't smart enough to integrate them.

I have the following accounts connected:

- Microsoft (i.e. Hotmail)
- Google (including Contacts)
- Facebook
- Linkedin
- Twitter

The contacts in question have entries from Google contacts as well as Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

To link contacts in People app:

1. Open a person's contact card
2. Right click and select "Link"
3. Select other contact card containing duplicate
4. Save contact

Not sure if this can be done automatically in any way though.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to connect to Windows Live (Hotmail) and make all your adjustments from there. I had to delete 540 contacts and it tool me 3 minutes. Hint: Use your keyboard shortcuts like Shift and Ctrl to select multiple contacts at once.

Answer (score 0):

The People App in Windows 8 will automatically link duplicate contacts from different networks, as is explained here:

> By connecting multiple accounts and linking your duplicate contacts,
> we’re able to create a contact card for everyone in your address book,
> regardless of how you’re connected to them.

Souce: [The People app: the complete, cloud-powered address book for Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919232117/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/06/13/the-people-app-the-complete-cloud-powered-address-book-for-windows-8.aspx)

In some cases you might want to manually link multiple contacts together. This can be done by opening up a contact and then open the app bar (by right clicking) and click "Link". Then select the contact you want to connect.

Comment: I ended up having to link a ton of contacts manually. I don't know why the People app didn't figure it out, despite the contacts having the same name.